# Get fieldname of getter by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I was never really strong in reflection and I seem to have stumped on a problem that seems trivial but doesn't turn out that way.  At least for me.  I have a bean with a few getters , then in a service I use Reflextion to loop over said methods and at a certain point I end up with the get method I want.  I invoke the method to get the value, and now I like to know the name of the field I just asked the value from.  There is it where I get stuck.

get method

```
public String getTest(){ return test }
```

invoking method by reflection

```
Object value = method.invoke(jsonObject, new Object[]{});
```

Now I like to do something like this

```
String fieldName = method.findTheNameOfTheField();
```

I find lots of examples to call the getter from the fieldname but nothing on how to do the reverse.  Is this even possible without parsing the name of the method and just cutting is and get from the method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I invoke the method to get the value, and now I like to know the name of the field I just asked the value from.

No, you can't do this - at least not without analyzing the bytecode itself. Don't forget that the getter can contain *any* code. Maybe it doesn't use a field. Maybe it uses more than one field. Maybe all the properties use a map. Maybe it uses a field, but then changes the result (e.g. copies a list).

You should consider whether a change in your design would remove the need for this in the first place - I can't think of many cases where it would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for this, it made me think indeed about my design.  Reason I needed this was because I was practicing with annotations.  Was my first go with them.  I was using @Validators({@Validator(name="notEmpty")}) on top of my get method.  The Idea was to use them in a validationService and the if validation failed send an error message back stating "(fieldname) has an error".  Thats why I needed the fieldname.  But I can just add it to the annotation I suppose @Validator(name=xxx, field=yyy)

Answer (score 1):

For working with JavaBeans, the Bean [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) makes life easier.

Tutorial

http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html

Examples

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/IntrospectingaBean.htm

http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2012/04/11/java-bean-introspector-and-covariantgeneric-returns/

http://www.javablogging.com/inspecting-your-java-beans/

http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/minimal-javabean-introspection-example.html

This uses reflection but hides much of the details like; Do I want `getValue` or `isFlag` for a getter.

Comment: Thnx some good reading material to get better with these kind of operations

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do here is to rely on the JavaBean convention, i.e. that the method `getFoo()` returns the value of the field `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

A getter may not necesarily return a field; here's a really trivial example

```
public getAge() {
  return currentdate - birthdate;
}
```

The whole point of getters is that they **may** return a field, but they may also return something else, abstracting internal logic from those who call the method.

Comment: yeah thnx I kinda figured that out allready , I was tired earlier and wasn't thinking straight , fixed it by adding the fieldname to the validator annotation